# Google Chrome security

Tags: networking, google-chrome

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

When I first open Google Chrome I get the green padlock, but any sites I visit I get `your connection is not private`.

I then check the connection and it has 2 warnings:

```
The website identity has not been verified.
```

and

```
Your connection to [Whatever website] is not encrypted.
```

I've checked everything in the settings. I'm no Debugger so at this point I'm 
lost. Even my ISP Home page has the issue. I’ve done time and date which are ok. Searched the web but no help! Any help here?

Comment: ...and why would an ISP page be encrypted?

Comment: My ISP has there own website which contains my webmai.l

Answer (score 0):

Only https connections are encrypted. If you are opening a website whose address starts with http:// (no "s") the connection is not encrypted.

Comment: Every website! Sorry but something else is going on